# IE9: how to forces 2 pages to display the same why? The first is in Quirks mode, the other IE7 Compatible

Tags: html, doctype

No matter what I try to do, pages keep looking significantly different depending on whether they are from my local machine or the development server. When pressing F12, I've finaly noticed that pages have different instructions on the top:

1) Pages displayed by my local machine have the following values:

**Browser Mode:** IE9 Compatible View

**Document Mode:** Quirks

HTML starts with this line of code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

2) Whereas pages displayed by the development server have the following values:

**Browser Mode:** IE9 Compatible View

**Document Mode:** IE7 Standards

HTML starts with this line of code

```
<!-- DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" -->

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

It looks like the the first line of the instruction that's making those pages to display differently.

Do I need to add that line to pages coming from my local machines as well? Why and how to do that?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a doctype, you are in quirks mode, and, no matter what else you do, pages won't look the same as in strict mode.

New web pages should always have a doctype and always use strict. Rarely would a newly created page have a need for quirks or the transitional doctype you are using.

Add either that transitional doctype on your first line or, preferably, the strict version:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Better yet, use the new type: `<!DOCTYPE html>` which will keep all browsers in strict mode, including IE back to IE6 (or even IE4? Don't recall).